Receiving TypeError: ReadableStream: Expected <ref *1> ReadableStream . Not sure where to begin
I'm running into an issue I'm unsure of how to debug or even how to begin.
When making an API request to either my OpenAI or ReplicateAI  on the local dev and build version of my Next.JS application I keep triggering a 500 error with a TypeError: ReadableStream: Expected <ref *1> ReadableStream. See Reference #1 for the full error text.
Although I receive the error it appears the request is successful. For ReplicateAI I am able to see my result in the dashboard.
This error does not exist on my deployed version and everything works as expected.
I haven't tried much as I'm not sure where to begin on this issue.
*** EDIT: I searched around and found switching NextResponse to Response resolved this issue. However I still don't understand WHY NextResponse is breaking on try but Response is working as expected.
I also noticed that my NEXTJS and typescript versions are set to 'latest', wondering if a breaking change in an update may cause this?
Reference #1: Error Message
[CONVERSATION_ERROR TypeError: ReadableStream: Expected <ref *1> ReadableStream {
  _state: 'readable',
  _reader: undefined,
  _storedError: undefined,
  _disturbed: false,
  _readableStreamController: ReadableByteStreamController {
    _controlledReadableByteStream: [Circular *1],
    _pullAgain: false,
    _pulling: false,
    _byobRequest: null,
    _queueTotalSize: 0,
    _queue: SimpleQueue {
      _cursor: 0,
      _size: 0,
      _front: [Object],
      _back: [Object]
    },
    _closeRequested: false,
    _started: false,
    _strategyHWM: 0,
    _pullAlgorithm: [Function: pullAlgorithm],
    _cancelAlgorithm: [Function: cancelAlgorithm],
    _autoAllocateChunkSize: undefined,
    _pendingPullIntos: SimpleQueue {
      _cursor: 0,
      _size: 0,
      _front: [Object],
      _back: [Object]
    }
  }
} to be an instance of ReadableStream.
    at webidl.errors.exception (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1679:14)
    at Object.ReadableStream (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1878:31)
    at webidl.converters.BodyInit (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4688:34)
    at new Response (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4396:36)
    at new NextResponse (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/response.js:38:9)
    at NextResponse.json (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/response.js:67:16)
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/conversation/route.ts:48:99)
    at async /Users/myName/Documents/Coding/myProject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:61466
 ✓ Compiled /(dashboard)/(routes)/music/page in 686ms (1838 modules)
 ✓ Compiled /api/music/route in 170ms (883 modules)
[MUSIC_ERROR TypeError: ReadableStream: Expected <ref *1> ReadableStream {
  _state: 'readable',
  _reader: undefined,
  _storedError: undefined,
  _disturbed: false,
  _readableStreamController: ReadableByteStreamController {
    _controlledReadableByteStream: [Circular *1],
    _pullAgain: false,
    _pulling: false,
    _byobRequest: null,
    _queueTotalSize: 0,
    _queue: SimpleQueue {
      _cursor: 0,
      _size: 0,
      _front: [Object],
      _back: [Object]
    },
    _closeRequested: false,
    _started: false,
    _strategyHWM: 0,
    _pullAlgorithm: [Function: pullAlgorithm],
    _cancelAlgorithm: [Function: cancelAlgorithm],
    _autoAllocateChunkSize: undefined,
    _pendingPullIntos: SimpleQueue {
      _cursor: 0,
      _size: 0,
      _front: [Object],
      _back: [Object]
    }
  }
} to be an instance of ReadableStream.
    at webidl.errors.exception (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1679:14)
    at Object.ReadableStream (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1878:31)
    at webidl.converters.BodyInit (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4688:34)
    at new Response (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4396:36)
    at new NextResponse (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/response.js:38:9)
    at NextResponse.json (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/response.js:67:16)
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/music/route.ts:47:99)
    at async /Users/MyName/Documents/Coding/MyProject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:61466

Reference #2: My Route Code
import { auth } from '@clerk/nextjs';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import OpenAI from 'openai';
import { increaseApiLimit, checkApiLimit } from '@/lib/api-limit';
import { checkSubscription } from '@/lib/subscription';

const openai = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: process.env.OPEN_API_KEY,
});

export async function POST(req: Request) {

    try {
        const { userId } = auth();
        const body = await req.json();
        const { messages } = body;

        if (!userId) {
            return new NextResponse("Unauthorized", { status: 401 })
        }

        if(!openai.apiKey) {
            return new NextResponse("openai API Key not configured")
        }

        if (!messages) {
            return new NextResponse("Messages are required", { status: 400 })
        }

        const freeTrial = await checkApiLimit();
        const isPro = await checkSubscription();

        if (!freeTrial && !isPro) {
            return new NextResponse("Free trial has expired.", {
                status: 403
            })
        }

        const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
            model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages
        })

        if (!isPro) await increaseApiLimit();

        return NextResponse.json(response.choices[0].message)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('[CONVERSATION_ERROR', error);
        return new NextResponse('Internal error', { status: 500 });
    }
}

Reference #3: Form to make the request
'use client';
import axios from 'axios';
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast';
import { Empty } from '@/components/Empty';
import { Loader } from '@/components/Loader';
import Heading from '@/components/Heading';
import { MessageSquare } from 'lucide-react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as z from 'zod';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import { formSchema } from './constants';
import { Form, FormControl, FormField, FormItem } from '@/components/ui/form';
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ChatCompletionMessageParam } from 'openai/resources/index.mjs';
import { cn } from '@/lib/utils';
import { UserAvatar } from '@/components/UserAvatar';
import { BotAvatar } from '@/components/BotAvatar';
import useProModal from '@/hooks/useProModal';

const ConversationPage = () => {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState<ChatCompletionMessageParam[]>([]);

    const router = useRouter();
    const proModal = useProModal();

    const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
        defaultValues: {
            prompt: '',
        },
    });

    const isResponseLoading = form.formState.isSubmitting;

    const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
        try {
            const userMessage: ChatCompletionMessageParam = {
                role: 'user',
                content: values.prompt,
            };
            const newMessages = [...messages, userMessage];

            const response = await axios.post('/api/conversation', {
                messages: newMessages,
            });

            setMessages((current) => [...current, userMessage, response.data]);

            form.reset();
        } catch (error: any) {
            if (error?.response?.status === 403) {
                proModal.onOpen();
            } else {
                toast.error("Something went wrong");
            }
        } finally {
            router.refresh();
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Heading
                title='Conversation'
                description='Our most advanced conversation model.'
                Icon={MessageSquare}
                iconColor='text-violet-500'
                bgColor='bg-violet-500/10'
            />
            <div className='px-4 lg:px-8'>
                <div>
                    <Form {...form}>
                        <form
                            onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                            className='
                                rounded-lg
                                border
                                w-full
                                p-4
                                px-3
                                md:px-6
                                focus-within:shadow-sm
                                grid
                                grid-cols-12
                                gap-2
                            '
                        >
                            <FormField
                                name='prompt'
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <FormItem className='col-span-12 lg:col-span-10'>
                                        <FormControl className='m-0 p-0'>
                                            <Input
                                                className='border-0 outline-none focus-visible:ring-0 focus-visible:ring-transparent'
                                                disabled={isResponseLoading}
                                                placeholder='How do I calculate the radius of a circle?'
                                                {...field}
                                            />
                                        </FormControl>
                                    </FormItem>
                                )}
                            />
                            <Button
                                className='col-span-12 lg:col-span-2 w-full'
                                disabled={isResponseLoading}
                            >
                                Generate
                            </Button>
                        </form>
                    </Form>
                </div>
                <div className='space-y-4 mt-4'>
                    {isResponseLoading && (
                        <div className='p-8 rounded-lg w-full flex items-center justify-center bg-muted'>
                            <Loader />
                        </div>
                    )}
                    {messages.length === 0 && !isResponseLoading && (
                        <Empty label={'No Conversation Started'} />
                    )}
                    <div className='flex flex-col-reverse gap-y-4'>
                        {messages.map((message, idx) => (
                            <div
                                key={`${message.content}-${idx}`}
                                className={cn(
                                    'p-8 w-full flex items-start gap-x-8 rounded-lg',
                                    message.role === 'user'
                                        ? 'bg-white border border-black/10'
                                        : 'bg-muted'
                                )}
                            >
                                {message.role === 'user' ? <UserAvatar /> : <BotAvatar />}
                                <p className='text-sm'>{message.content}</p>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ConversationPage;


Unfortunately I don't have an answer as to why this works, but I just replaced NextResponse with Response and all works as expected.
